# iOS - How to set iOS to ask for the passcode only on boot?

Tags: iphone, ios, password

I need to make an iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2) ask for the password only after boot, so I can use it and close the screen when it's already on without the need of writing my passcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing like this exists for iOS devices. You can either set it up to ask for a passcode all the time or never, but not only when you turn it back on after restarting.